# Can is possible to hide one of Tabs in TabBar?

Tags: flutter, tabs, tabbar

I have TabBar with three tabs and I want to 'hide' actual tab. When tab is switched, the previous should show and actual tab should hide. I did something like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR7m7.jpg

Text in second row, below TabBar it's just a simple text based on what Tab is active right now.

but it's only changing width and as you can see it's not perfect solution. It's hard to position it and when tab is clicked it's visible for user that clicked tab is just small.

For what I know with flutter TabBar it's not possible, but maybe there is a package which will allow me to do something like this?

Here is my code: https://controlc.com/a9224c6e

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited my answer, I added link @YeasinSheikh

Comment: this is not minimal , you see I’ve to edit a lost of thing to produce the issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited it once again, I hope it is better now